# Need to collapse/expand part of appbar on button click

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout

I got a [layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uivbW.png) where i need to expand/collapse the part of appbarlayout on click of button in a toolbar.
I know how to do all the stuff, except the hide/show itself. I tried to use `AppBarLayout.setExpanded(false)` but its not working.
Here is my XML

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.softdeal.gazdaifua.activity.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:id="@+id/main_appbar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_filter"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_filter_list_white_48dp" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_plus_button" />
```